# java.nio.Files, java.nio.Paths on java 6

Tags: java, file, io, nio, glob

I need to rewrite some java 7 file IO code that should run on a Java 6 VM too.

The implementation uses handy Java 7 features like autoclosing, `Paths` and `Files`.

To be more specific, I need to handle expressions like `/tmp/foo/*.bar` to return all *.bar* files (currently implemented with `Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, glob)`).

Does anyone know a handy library for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) API would be a good candidate for this, in particular their FileSet class might do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) API is also a good choice. I used it for a similar work (rewrite some code from java7 to java6 that used Path object) and they work very well.

Answer (score 0):

[guava](https://github.com/google/guava) runs on java6 and it has a nice [I/O api](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IOExplained).